# Does this correctly interpret the "$\cong$" between groups as "$=$" between sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to give the wording "isomorphic groups have the same structure" a precise interpretation, at least for the finite order case. A positive answer to my final question would reach the goal, as it would translate a "$\cong$" between groups into a "$=$" between sets.

For $n$ positive integer, let be:

- $I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$;
- $G$, $\overline G$ groups of order $n$;
- $\psi\colon G \rightarrow \overline G$ isomorphism;
- $f$, $\bar f$ bijections;
- $\theta$, $\bar \theta$ embeddings;
- in general, $\varphi^{(\alpha)}$ the isomorphism between symmetric groups on sets of the same cardinality, defined by $\sigma \mapsto (g \mapsto (\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})(g))$, where $\alpha$ is a bijection between the sets;
- $S_n$ the symmetric group of degree $n$.

Visually:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
   I_n     &   &    I_n      \\
    \da{f}         &           &     \da{\bar f}          \\
   G & \ras{\psi} &    \overline G  \\
    \da{\theta}         &           &     \da{\bar \theta}          \\
   \operatorname{Sym}(G) & \ras{\varphi^{(\psi)}} &    \operatorname{Sym}(\overline G)  \\
    \da{\varphi^{(f)}}         &           &     \da{\varphi^{(\bar f)}}          \\
   S_n &  &    S_n  \\
\end{array}
$$

> Is it $(\varphi^{(f)}\circ\theta)(G)=(\varphi^{(\bar f)}\circ\bar \theta)(\overline G)$?

Comment: See [Group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism).

Comment: A group is a set with a law describing how elements interact. An equality between group would mean the sets are equals (hence, the same), same for the law. Isomorphism enables to go from groups of functions or polynomials to integers, for example. But a set of function cannot equal to a set of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those things need not be equal "for trivial reasons": you can take $G = G'$, and $\theta = \theta'$, and $\psi$ to be the identity (although it doesn't even factor into the equation you're asking about), but take $f \neq \bar f$. Then trivially $\theta(G) = \theta'(G')$, but the mappings $f, f'$ give different isomorphisms $\phi^{(f)}$ and $\phi^{(f')}$, so that you get different images in $S_n$. Concretely, you could take $G = C_4$ with generator $g$, and let $\theta$ be the Cayley embedding, and let $f(k) = g^k$, while $f'(1) = g, f'(2) = g^3, f'(3) = g^2, f'(4) = e$, so that $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ is in $(\phi^{(f)} \circ \theta)(G)$ but not in $(\phi^{(f')} \circ \theta')(G')$.

The problem with this is not that group isomorphism is the wrong notion, it's that you're asking the wrong question about it. It would work better with the following changes: suppose that $f, f'$ have the additional condition that $\psi \circ f = f'$, and that $\theta, \theta'$ are the Cayley embeddings for $G, G'$, then do the two mappings $I_n \to S_n$ given by
$$
\phi^{(f)} \circ \theta \circ f \qquad \text{and} \qquad \phi^{(f')} \circ \theta' \circ f'
$$
agree? And indeed the answer is that they do. For take $i, k \in I_n$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi^{(f)}(\theta(f(i)))(k) &= f^{-1}(\theta(f(i))(f(k)))\\
&= f^{-1}(f(i)f(k))\\
&= f^{-1}\psi^{-1}\psi(f(i)f(k))\\
&= (f^{-1}\psi^{-1})(\psi(f(i))\psi(f(k)))\\
&= f'^{-1}(f'(i)f'(k))\\
&= f'^{-1}(\theta'(f'(i))(f'(k)))\\
&= \phi^{(f')}(\theta'(f'(i)))(k).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you for having gone further than my bare question: your "additional condition" has been very helpful in my reasoning.

Comment: And also moving from general embeddings to particular ones ("Cayley") I see it's another key point in my view.

Comment: Since $\theta'=\varphi^{(\psi)}\theta\psi^{-1}$ irrespective of the embeddings being Cayley or not, this latter qualification seems not to be relevant in the result you got to (while $f'=\psi f$ is really key). Cayley just ensures that such embeddings exist.

Comment: @Luca No, this is not true for general embeddings.

Comment: @verret Ok, I got the point. So, let's keep stick to Cayley's embedding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot meaningfully have a bijection between a set and a group.

You can have a bijection between a set and the *underlying set* of a group, but the underlying set does not in general fix the group up to isomorphism, you can have non-isomorphic groups of the same order (same number of group elements). The simplest example being the cyclic group of order $4$ versus the Klein four-group:

- The set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ together with addition modulo $4$ (that is, add the numbers, and then if you get beyond $3$, subtract $4$ to get back into the set) gives, up to isomorphism, the cyclic group of order $4$.
- The set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ together with bitwise xor (that is write the number as two-bit binary, form the two-bit string that has an $1$ in positions where the bits of the two operands differ and a $0$ where they don't, and interpret the result as number) is isomorphic to the Klein four-group.

Those groups are very different. For example, in the cyclic group, $1+1=2\ne 0$, but in the Klein four-group, $n+n=0$ for all $n$ (nowhere do the bits of an element differ from the bits of itself!).

So your scheme fails at the very first step, defining a bijection between a set and a group.