# Can I interpret the "$\cong$" between finite groups as an "$=$" between sets in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

[This post is admittedly a development of [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501351/does-this-correctly-interpret-the-cong-between-groups-as-between-sets/3501398#3501398) of mine, based on therein accepted answer.]

> Here I kindly ask for a "solution verification" of my final interpretation.

---

For $n$ positive integer, let be:

- $I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$;
- $G$, $\overline G$ groups of order $n$;
- $\psi\colon G \rightarrow \overline G$ isomorphism;
- $f$ bijection and $\bar f = \psi f$;
- $\theta$, $\bar \theta$ Cayley embeddings;
- in general, $\varphi^{(\alpha)}$ the isomorphism between symmetric groups on sets of the same cardinality, defined by $\sigma \mapsto (g \mapsto (\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})(g))$, where $\alpha$ is a bijection between the sets;
- $S_n$ the symmetric group of degree $n$.

Visually:

[image]

Then:

$$\varphi^{(f)} \theta f = \varphi^{(\bar f)} \bar \theta \bar f \tag 1$$

*Proof*. Since $\varphi^{(\bar f)}=\varphi^{(f)}(\varphi^{(\psi)})^{-1}$ and (*) $\bar\theta=\varphi^{(\psi)}\theta\psi^{-1}$, we get:

$$\varphi^{(\bar f)} \bar\theta \bar f = \varphi^{(f)}(\varphi^{(\psi)})^{-1}\varphi^{(\psi)}\theta\psi^{-1}\psi f = \varphi^{(f)}\theta f$$

$\Box$

My interpretation of $(1)$ is as follows:

> If two (finite) groups are isomorphic (via $\psi$), then, for a given labelling of the elements of the first one (via $f^{-1}$), a labelling of the elements of the second one exists (given by $f^{-1}\psi^{-1}$) such that the two groups' *structures* manifest in $S_n$ as *one same set* (by $(1)$, actually).

---

**Edit**. As pointed out in the comments, (*) needs not to be true, unless the embeddings are Cayley's. Anyway, since these latter always exist, the conclusion keeps unaltered.

---

**Edit #2**. If we'd define *structure of $G$* (under a given labelling $f^{-1}$) the map $\varphi^{(f)}\theta f$, where $\theta$ is Cayley embedding of $G$ into $S_G$, then $(1)$ would precisely state that *isomorphic groups have the same structure*.

---

**Edit #3**. I think we can upgrade this result to an "iff" one.

Let:

[image]

where, for $n$ positive integer:

- $I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$;
- $G$, $\overline G$ are groups of order $n$;
- $f$, $\bar f$ are bijections;
- $\theta$, $\bar \theta$ are Cayley embeddings;
- in general, $\varphi^{(\alpha)}$ is the isomorphism between symmetric groups on sets of the same cardinality, defined by $\sigma \mapsto (g \mapsto (\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})(g))$, where $\alpha$ is a bijection between the sets;
- $S_n$ is the symmetric group of degree $n$.

**Claim**. Let $f$, $\bar f$, $G$, $\overline G$, $\theta$ and $\bar \theta$ be as above. Then $G \cong \overline G$ if and only if:

$$\exists  f,\bar f \mid \varphi^{(f)}\theta f = \varphi^{(\bar f)}\bar \theta\bar f \tag 1$$

*Proof*. $\Rightarrow$) Let $\psi$ be the isomorphism between $G$ and $\overline G$; then, for any $f$, the bijection $\bar f := \psi f$ does the job (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3501396/615081) for the proof). $\Leftarrow$) Let $(1)$ hold for some $f$ and $\bar f$; then $\bar f f^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $\overline G$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508676/615081) for the proof). $\quad \Box$

Comment: Not at all a duplicate, in my opinion: the linked question (mine) asked about the correctedness of a guessed equation, which turned out not to be correct as such. This post (mine as well) acknowledges the fixed equation to give an interpretation of this latter. If someone relies on the linked question only, he/she gets very little.

Comment: I don't think this is true. For example, a cyclic group of order $10$ can be embedded as a regular subgroup of $S_{10}$, but also as an intransitive one and these cannot be mapped to one another by an automorphism of $S_{10}$. Your proof doesn't actually do anything, you just restate what you want as fact. For example, why is  $\bar\theta=\varphi^{(\psi)}\theta\psi^{-1}$ true? (It's not, as I just explained.) Now, if you assume that the embeddings are actually Cayley embeddings, then I think it is true, but it requires a little bit of work (but is actually well known).

Comment: Note that Mees de Vries in answering your previous question was careful to assume that $\theta$ and $\overline{theta}$ were Cayley embeddings. If you assume that you have Cayley embeddings, then the proof was already given by Mees de Vries, which is why this was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @verret All true and well recorded, thanks (and my credits to Mees just opened this post). Anyway, my focus wasn't on embeddings making $(1)$ true (if just Cayley's, ok, that's enough for my aim). I was rather interested in giving wordings like "isomorphic groups have the same structure" (or the plethora of  similar ones) a sounder algebraic justification, a goal to whom the "duplicated" thread was purely ancillary and only achieved (in my view) in the final interpretation of this post. The accepted answer hereunder keeps perfect to me, with the only amendment that you have  put in evidence.

Comment: I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The post is still wrong, as it claims something is true for arbitrary embeddings, which is not.

Comment: Moreover, I don't agree that you've done anything like give the phrase "isomorphic groups have the same structure" a sounder algebraic justification.

Permutation groups are in a sense a different category than groups. They have their own notion of isomorphism: see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Permutation_isomorphic_groups

Comment: All you've done is claimed that if two isomorphic (abstract) groups are given "compatible" embeddings in isomorphic symmetric group, then they are permutation isomorphic, which is almost tautological. You've just switched from one kind of isomorphic, to another type of isomorphism.

Comment: In the edit I've said that (*) holds for Cayley's embeddings only, which is enough to state that $(1)$ holds for any pair of isomorphic groups. I don't see where still it's said that the embeddings are arbitrary.

Comment: The only I wanted to get was a construction starting from *two isomorphic groups* and bringing them to *one same set*, as "tangilble" proof of their structures being the same. I'm hoping to have done it by means of $(1)$.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question as it builds on, rather than duplicates, the original, answered question.

Comment: In your post, you say "for $n$ positive integer", etc. then "let be ... $\theta$ embeddings" etc. In math, this means that whatever comes next should hold for all $\theta$, not for some $\theta$. That's why the post is still wrong. Furthermore, if all you wanted was to get the groups "on the same set", then any old group isomorphism does that. A group isomorphism includes a bijection from one ground set to the other, so they are now "on the same set". Getting the symmetric groups involved only serves to change the category, as I explained earlier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does this correctly interpret the "$\cong$" between groups as "$=$" between sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501351/does-this-correctly-interpret-the-cong-between-groups-as-between-sets)

Comment: @verret Possibly it would be better if you could write up your points as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

It means that corresponding elements (of $G$ and $\bar G$) receive the same label (from $I_n$ where $n=|G|$), and by the isomorphism they behave exactly the same way (generating the exact same permutations on the labels).

Comment: This is not true for general embeddings of $G$ and $\overline{G}$ in $S_G$ and $S_{\overline{G}}$, see comments to the question.

Comment: See my comment above.