# Does $\alpha=\beta f \Rightarrow f$ isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

For a positive integer $n$, let be:

- $K$ and $H$ finite groups of order $n$;
- $S_n$ the symmetric group of degree $n$;
- $\alpha\colon K \hookrightarrow S_n$ and $\beta\colon H \hookrightarrow S_n$ embeddings;
- $f\colon K \rightarrow H$ bijection.

Does $\alpha=\beta f \Rightarrow f$ isomorphism? If not in general, is that true for some conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

---

**Edit** based on @Matthias Klupsch's hint:

$(\beta f)(xy)=\beta(f(xy))$; but $\beta f$ and $\beta$ are, in particular, homomorphisms, so: $(\beta f)(xy)=((\beta f)(x))((\beta f)(y))=(\beta(f(x))(\beta(f(y))=\beta(f(x)f(y))$; therefore, $\beta(f(xy))=\beta(f(x)f(y))$; but $\beta$ is injective, so $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, and $f$ is homomorphism and hence isomorphism.

Comment: You already know that $f$ is bijective, have you tried showing that it is a homomorphism?

Comment: About $f$, I know that it is a bijection and that it makes $\alpha=\beta f$, only. I don't know its explicit definition.

Comment: I was asking if you have already tried to prove that $f$ is a homomorphism and if you have, then it might be a good idea to share how far you came in your approach.

Comment: I tried for a while, but I couldn't get to a starting point.

Comment: Here's a hint: write $\alpha(xy) = \alpha(x)\alpha(y)$ a bit more complicated using your identity.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch I've edited according to your hint: does it fit?

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that you haven't used finiteness anywhere, only that $\beta$ and $\beta f$ are injective homomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that given groups $G,K,H$ with embeddings $\alpha: K\to G$ and $\beta : H\to G$, any bijection $f:K\to H$ satisfying $\alpha = \beta f$ is necessarily an isomorphism. We don't need to impose any further restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof that $f$ is a homomorphism.

We need to prove that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. Since $\beta$ is injective, it suffices to prove that $\beta(f(xy))=\beta(f(x)f(y))$. This is the key idea.

Indeed,

$\quad \beta(f(xy)) = \alpha(xy) = \alpha(x) \alpha(y)$, because $\alpha$ is a homomorphism

$\quad \beta(f(x)f(y)) = \beta(f(x)) \beta(f(y)) = \alpha(x) \alpha(y)$, because $\beta$ is a homomorphism

and we're done.